# If $\{v_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a basic sequence then is $\{v_n+v_0\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a basic sequence too?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $V$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $\{v_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset V$ be a basic sequence in $V$

Let $v_0 \in V$ such that $v_0 \notin \{v_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$

My question is:

Is the sequence $\{v_n+v_0\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a basic sequence ?

Thanks.

Comment: If $v_0=-v_1$, then $0$ is in the sequence $v_n+v_0$.

Comment: ok @conditionalMethod thanks, an further question, if $v_0 \notin span \{v_n\}$?

Comment: In $\ell_2$, let $V=[ e_i : i>1]$. Set $v_n=e_{n+1}$, for $n\ge1$ and $v_0=e_1$. Then $(v_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a basis of $V$. Set $y_n=v_0+v_n$. then $\sum_{i=1}^n y_n$ has norm of order $\sqrt{n^2+n}$, while $\sum_{i=1}^n y_n-\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n} y_n$ has norm of order $\sqrt{2n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.

Let $(e_i)$ be the standard unit vector basis of $\ell_2$. Take $v_n=e_{n+1}$ for $n\ge1$ and $v_0=e_1$. Then $(v_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a basic sequence whose closed linear span does not contain $e_1$.

Let $y_n=v_n+v_0$ for $n\ge1$. Note that for each $n$, the norm of $$e_1-\sum_{i=1}^n{1\over n} y_n=(0,\underbrace{ 1/n,1/n,\ldots,1/n,}_{(n-1)\rm - terms}\ 0,\ldots)$$ is $\sqrt{(n-1)/n^2}$. It follows from this that $e_1$ is in the closed linear span of the $y_i$.

But, a moment's thought reveals that $e_1$ cannot be written in the form $\sum\alpha_i y_i$; thus, $(y_i)$ is not basic.

(Alternatively, one can show the projections associated to $(y_i)$ are not uniformly bounded; see my comment above.)

Comment: thanks @DavidMitra for your answer